# is there a tab snooze plugin for Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

I've been looking around on DuckDuckGo and App Store for a Safari plugin that will let me "snooze" (similar to [this Chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-snooze/pdiebiamhaleloakpcgmpnenggpjbcbm)). Coming from Chrome, I've really come to rely on the ability to just set a timer and kick tabs off to the background for a period of time and then return (this also frees up memory).

So far I've found nothing. I'm hoping I'm just bad at searching and am missing something.

Comment: Something like a bookmark? :-) well, ok, the automatic reopening won‘t work then.

Comment: Alternatively one can always add page to Reminders using 'Share' in Safari title bar and set time. This way reminder notification will be displayed and not the tab though but this notification will contain link to the webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Snoozz](https://github.com/rohanb10/snoozz-tab-snoozing/blob/master/docs/safari.md). It works in Safari with some caveats. From the docs:

> What's broken?
>
> Snoozing windows: This requires use of the tabs API. Using that API,
> you will see a privacy popup every single time you try to snooze a
> website you have not snoozed before. The popup explicitly states Grant
> the extension permission to read all your data on this site which is
> going to put off a lot of users.
>
> Notifications: Safari does not support the notifications API.
>
> Keyboard Shortcuts: Safari does not let you configure your own
> keyboard shortcuts.
>
> Inconsistent wake up times: Safari does not support the idle API. It
> is used to calculate the next tab to wake up after your computer comes
> back from standby. It's very likely that your tabs will not wake up
> until you interact with the extension in any way.
>
> UI bugs: This extension was designed for Chrome and Firefox, so things
> might look a teeny bit off.